# The argument 'path' must be a string, Uint8Array, or URL without null bytes. Received '\x00@astro-page:astro/assets/endpoint/node' on Heroku deploy

Tags: heroku, server-side-rendering, astrojs

I modified my Astro web app to use an SSR ( the web app is a blog, so I want dynamic routes for all the posts inside the blog).

Seems that the app is working fine on my local PC, but when I'm trying to deploy it to heroku it fails with this error-

```html
    10:09:58 PM [content] No content directory found. Skipping type generation.
       10:09:58 PM [build] output target: server
       10:09:58 PM [build] deploy adapter: @astrojs/node
       10:09:58 PM [build] Collecting build info...
       10:09:58 PM [build] Completed in 495ms.
       10:09:58 PM [build] Building server entrypoints...

[vite:load-fallback] Could not load @astro-page:astro/assets/endpoint/node (imported by @astrojs-ssr-virtual-entry): The argument 'path' must be a string, Uint8Array, or URL without null bytes. Received '\x00@astro-page:astro/assets/endpoint/node'
 error   Could not load @astro-page:astro/assets/endpoint/node (imported by @astrojs-ssr-virtual-entry): The argument 'path' must be a string, Uint8Array, or URL without null bytes. Received '\x00@astro-page:astro/assets/endpoint/node'
TypeError [PLUGIN_ERROR]: Could not load @astro-page:astro/assets/endpoint/node (imported by @astrojs-ssr-virtual-entry): The argument 'path' must be a string, Uint8Array, or URL without null bytes. Received '\x00@astro-page:astro/assets/endpoint/node'
    at open (node:internal/fs/promises:586:10)
    at Object.readFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1044:20)
    at Object.load (file:///tmp/build_73de6bf3/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:47019:28)
    at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///tmp/build_73de6bf3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25439:28)
    at async file:///tmp/build_73de6bf3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24606:75
    at async Queue.work (file:///tmp/build_73de6bf3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25649:32)
-----> Build failed
```

I have installed the adapter as instructed like this

```
npm install @astrojs/node
```

and in the astro.config.mjs this is my configuration

```html
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import vue from "@astrojs/vue";
import node from "@astrojs/node";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [vue()],
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
  },
  output: 'server',
  adapter: node({
    mode: "middleware"
  })
});
```

this is my package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "astrowebsite",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro build",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/node": "^6.0.4",
    "@astrojs/tailwind": "^5.0.0",
    "@astrojs/vue": "^3.0.0",
    "@caisy/rich-text-astro-renderer": "^1.0.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.7",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.4.1",
    "astro": "^3.1.3",
    "astro-bootstrap": "^0.6.1",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "mdb-vue-ui-kit": "^4.1.0",
    "portal-vue": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-easy-lightbox": "^1.16.0",
    "vue-gallery": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-markdown": "^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

This is how I do the dynamic routing in my app

```html
const response = await fetch(
  "<My heroku url that I do the fetch from>"
);
const { data } = await response.json();
const { slug } = Astro.params;
const page = data.find((project) => project.attributes.title === slug);
if (!page) return Astro.redirect("/404");
const { id, attributes } = page;
```

What are those endpoints that Heroku talks about? how is using an SSR connected to that?
The Heroku server framework is nodejs, and I don't understand how to tackle this problem... I can't seem to find enough documentation on it or understand from the error what I'm supposed to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I transferred my Astro SSR app to Vercel because Heroku doesn't support SSR :-)